# ValueError at /feedback/by/XXX/new Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: XXX>>": "Model.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build this feedback application for the students to give feedback to their teachers. I am getting the following error when I try to create an instance of the feedback form. Please help. Thanks.

**Error:**

```
ValueError at /feedback/by/XXX/new
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: XXX>>": "Feedback.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

**CreateView:**

```
class CreateFeedback(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = FeedbackForm
    model = models.Feedback

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Form:**

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("teacher", "subject", "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4",
                    "param5", "param6", "param7", "param8", "param9", "param10")
        model = models.Feedback
```

**Path in urls.py:**

```
path('by/<username>/new',views.CreateFeedback.as_view(),name='create'),
```

**Models.py:**

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'feedback', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
        teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, related_name = 'feedback', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
        subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name = 'feedback', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
        param1 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param3 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param4 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param5 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param6 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param7 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param8 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param9 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        param10 = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse(
                "feedback:detail",
                kwargs={"username": self.user.username, "pk": self.pk})

        def __str__(self):
            return (self.username + "->" + self.teacher)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ["teacher"]
            unique_together = ["user", "teacher", "subject"]

class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier Django was allowing an integer to assign to a user object, but don't know since when, but it needs a user object only.

To fix your issue

Replace the following line

`self.object.user = self.request.user`

with following one

`self.object.user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)`

Comment: still getting the same error. kindly have a look at the complete code at https://github.com/salonikalra/feedback

Comment: provide the full traceback.

Comment: It seems you are importing `User` in views from  django `auth_user` model and in models you are referencing `User` from `accounts.models`. So you should pass `User` object from `account.models` to feedback form and not from `auth_user`

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the new traceback that I am getting. http://dpaste.com/2MJZAV1

Comment: That says the user you are looking for is not in the table. Try using self.request.user . That should work.